# Packages in default project

Tags: julia

I'm new to Julia.

Situation) I made a (local project, e.g., by `Pkg.activate(".")` and use a package which is installed in default project but not in the local one, i.e., `using package_installed_only_in_the_default_one`.
So I was confused.

Question) Are the packages in the default project shared and can be used in other projects?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer to your question is yes, if you use a default value of `LOAD_PATH` variable.

Here is a more detailed explanation.

What you ask for is managed by the [LOAD_PATH](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/constants/#Base.LOAD_PATH) variable  which specifies what `using` and `import` statements consider as project environments or package directories when loading code.

As you can read in the Julia manual entry on [Environment stacks](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/code-loading/#Environment-stacks) you have the following rules:

> There are a couple of noteworthy features of this design:
>
> 1. The primary environment—i.e. the first environment in a stack—is faithfully embedded in a stacked environment. The full dependency graph of the first environment in a stack is guaranteed to be included intact in the stacked environment including the same versions of all dependencies.
> 2. Packages in non-primary environments can end up using incompatible versions of their dependencies even if their own environments are entirely compatible. This can happen when one of their dependencies is shadowed by a version in an earlier environment in the stack (either by graph or path, or both).

Now by default `LOAD_PATH` has value `["@", "@v#.#", "@stdlib"]` which means that:

1. `@` refers to the "current active environment" (this is the primary environment mentioned above that you have activated)
2. `@v#.#` refers to the appropriate environment in ~/.julia/environments/ folder. The `#` characters, are replaced with the major and minor components of the Julia version number.
3. `@stdlib` expands to the absolute path of the current Julia installation's standard library directory.